# Can I use Spring Security's AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter to handle authentication as part of /oauth/authorize request handling?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

In our application I want to use Spring Security to implement authentication filtering as part of requests to /oauth/authorize.  I have added filters and providers - extending `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` - to provide custom authentication.
But I don't know what to do when implementing `AuthenticationSuccessHandler#onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)` so that the filtering of the request does not result in a redirection response to the browser - but instead the program continues to the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint#authorize(...)` intended to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this seems to be a valid approach to authentication in the filter chain ahead of reaching Spring's own /oauth/authorize request handler.

In our case earlier work had set 'AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer' endpoints mappings which was interfering with my authentication success handler's attempts to forward the request onwards.

So, my implementation includes a custom authentication filter extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, integrated into the Spring security filter chain via WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter,

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
// ... 
    .addFilterBefore(
        passwordLessAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
// ...
```

The custom PasswordLessAuthenticationFilter is constructed with an ant path matcher value, e.g. "/foo/oauth/authorize".
The custom filter is defined to store a reference to an instance Spring's ForwardAuthenticationSuccessHandler with a forward url value of "oauth/authorize".